# Are the number and colours of cards in player's hands private information?

Tags: viticulture

Is a player allowed to ask, and get an accurate answer for, the number of a given colour of card in an opponents hand?

For example: I want to know the number of yellow (summer visitor) cards in an opponents hand, to decide if I can safely make other actions and wait to play my own yellow card, is my opponent obligated to tell me this information, or at least show me their hand (face down) so I can see for myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the rules link [here](https://boardgamegeek.com/filepage/99700/final-rulebook-second-printing) it says on page 2.

> All information on a
>   player’s vineyard mat as well
>   as available workers, amount
>   of lira, and number of cards
>   is public information and
>   cannot be concealed.

This specifically says 'All information'  That would certainly include the colour on the back of the card.  If a player has to clearly display how many cards they have when asked then the colours will be visible.

The game didn't come with screens and cards are also taken from stacks publicly so I see no reason why it would be then secret.  It strikes me that your opponent refusing to tell you is incredibly unsporting and just that player trying to gain what every spurious advantage they can!

Comment: think you are parsing the sentence wrong. To me it says that the public information is (1) all information on a player’s vineyard mat, (2) available workers, (3) amount of lira, and (4) number of cards

Comment: You may be right but I think it comes down to the spirit of the game.  Cards are taken publicly.  Nothing in the rules states that the backs of cards are ever hidden.  For players to try and argue they shouldn't have to say what types of cards they have based on that rules is horrible clutching at straws to bend rules to there advantage and sucking all fun out of the hobby! I'll edit answer to clarify that knowing numbers of cards must also mean knowing the colours.

Comment: Agreed; to make the total number of cards in hand public, while making the numbers of each type private, would be very clunky and awkward. You wouldn't be able to hold your cards in your hand, like you naturally would, so you'd have to keep them hidden under the table or something. And then continually be asked how many cards you have. The natural interpretation is that you simply hold your cards like you would normally hold a hand of cards; and players can see from your hand how many you have and which types.